# canvas in HTML5 and creating multiple circles

Tags: html, canvas

following the w3c school explanation of canvas, I understand creating shapes...

```
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 20;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();
</script>
```

This will make a green circle where my canvas is.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

However - I want to apply that "circle" to multiple places on the page, and doing this by ID would be ridiculous.

How does one apply a context (as defined above) to multiple canvas'?? I' assume using class, this seems the logical way.

```
<canvas class="redDot"></canvas>
<canvas class="redDot"></canvas>
<canvas class="redDot"></canvas>

<canvas class="greenDot"></canvas>
<canvas class="greenDot"></canvas>

<canvas class="blueDot"></canvas>
<canvas class="blueDot"></canvas>
<canvas class="blueDot"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to iterate through each Element to apply the changes. I.E:

```
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dots');
for (var i=0;i<dots.length;i++){
    var canvas = dots[i];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Draw circles here 
}
```

Ideally, you would only have one canvas element which you can draw multiple circles

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myOneAndOnlyCanvas');
// Using CSS and layering can make background
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

dot('red',50,50);
dot('blue',100,50);
//etc..

function dot(color,x,y){
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(y, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();
}
```

But if that doesn't fit your use case what about using an SVG object?

Since you mentioned w3 schools: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/
But ideally check out: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/

Mind, Dom Heavy pages can seriously hurt load times. Depending on what you want to do it might be wiser just to use an image (eg. a large cluster of dots).

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the context also as a parameter? There's only one context per canvas element, and in this function I think you're calling the same canvas context always

Comment: In the second snippet? That's the point. Use only one Canvas.

Comment: @Dylan, i guess the point about the DOM is important, I 'assumed' that rendering colors would be LESS of a resource than calling an image. - it'll certianlly make my code easier if Im just doing the old "image" solution

Comment: @DylanMadisetti I thought about that too in the first instance, but I'm not sure if there's a real need to have separate canvas objects, as it is stated on the question...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There is no clear answer without context. Also, made my answer a bit more explicit

Comment: If it's only circles you want, can also use border-radius
http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/